# repository pattern with specification pattern in java

Tags: java, repository-pattern, specification-pattern

I am trying to implement the repository pattern to query users and the corresponding settings associated to each user. I am having a repository interface which has the crud operations to be implemented by each and every repository.

```
import java.util.List;

public interface Repository<T> {

    void add(T item);
    void add(Iterable<T> items);
    void update(T item);
    void remove(T item);
    void remove(Specification specification);
    List<T> query(Specification specification);

}
```

I am reading about the specification pattern but i do not understand how to apply the concept to my usecase.

I have two repositories which implements the Repository interface. My classes will be having the below operations which translate into the crud operations as mentioned in the interface

```
GetSettingsForUserIDMatchingSettingName(string userid, string settingname);
CreateSettingForProfile(string userid, Setting setting);
Create(string userid, Setting setting);
Update(string userid, Setting setting); 
GetAllProfiles();
GetProfilesMatchingUserID(string userid);
GetSettingsForUserID(string userid);        
GetProfilesForUserIDWithSettingName(string userid, string settingname);
```

How to create my specification class or interface so that my specification caters to all the use cases.

I am referring to the below github link to implement but i am lost.

https://github.com/patrikfr/specification/blob/master/specification/src/com/granular8/specification/genericspec/Specification.java

Kindly, help.

Comment: There are many ways to implement specs. Maybe this helps you https://dzone.com/articles/java-using-specification

Answer (score 0):

Specification pattern can help if you are querying or if you need it for filtering the objects that you want to delete from a certain repository thats fine. There is a good implementation of the pattern in C#. Hopefully you translate it to Java since it already supports lambda expressions.
https://github.com/jnicolau/NSpecifications